# TS - Duplicate Function implementation in TypeScript even though the code doesn't have anything else in the file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn TS on my own. I wrote a function and until I write the file, there's no issue. But as soon as I try to compile it, the error squiggly shows that I'm have a Duplicate Function implementation issue.

[image]

Comment: It's happening on compile. Any function I write, I get the same error.

Comment: What I did later on was this -

var AW = function(a:number, b:string) {
}

And this worked for me!!

Comment: This can happen if you have compiled to JavaScript, and you included the .js file in tsconfig.json, or you don't have a tsconfig.json and the .js file is in the same directory as the .ts file. Both the .ts and .js files declare the function with the same name, hence the error.

Comment: Oh!! Now I see why. Thanks a lot, kaya3! :) I've a long way to go. Cheers!